# my iphone app doesn't run. cause dyld: Symbol not found: UIPointerInteraction

Tags: ios, uikit, uipointerinteraction

I made an app for iphone in Xcode 13.2.

I set the minimum supported OS to 11.0 and there was no problem when compiling.

However, I recently tested it on an iPhone 6 with iOS 12.4, and the app crashed as soon as it started.

When debugging, the following message is output, but I do not know why this problem occurred.

Has anyone solved the same issue in this regard? If yes, how did you solve it?

Here is the debugging message I saw

dyld: Symbol not found: *OBJC_CLASS*$_UIPointerInteraction
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/"AppID"/Myapp.app/Myapp Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UiKit.framework/UIKit in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/"AppID"/Myapp.app/Myapp

P.s. My app is for iPhone only. So I disabled both iPad and Mac support settings in the targets deployment info.

PS 2. When I searched for UIPointerInteraction in my code, there was no result. Of course I didn't even use it.

I am eagerly awaiting your reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this issue, so I'm leaving a comment.

The cause was a library added to my project.

The library was compiled by myself and the minimum version was set to 13.6.

I recompiled the min version to 11.0 and that solved the problem.

Thanks